# How can I insert data into a specific row in mySQL database?

Tags: mysql, pdo

I want to insert data in my SQL database:

```php
try {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO animals (size) values(?) WHERE id = '$name'";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    foreach($animalarray as $row) {
        if (array_key_exists('size',$row)) {
            $q->execute(array($row['size']));
        }
    }
}
catch (PDOException $pe) {
    echo $pe->getMessage();
}
catch (Exception $e ) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
Database::disconnect();
```

But I get the error message:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = 'horse '' at line 1

---

I updated my code according to the answer of **@G_hi3**. Now it works. My mistake was that I tried to use `INSERT` instead of `UPDATE`:

```php
try {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $update_animal = "UPDATE animals SET size='$size' WHERE id = '$name'";
    $sql = $pdo->prepare($update_animal);
    $sql->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $pe) {
    echo $pe->getMessage();
}
catch (Exception $e ) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
Database::disconnect();
```

Comment: Print out the raw SQL query in your PHP code and add it to the question.  It should be obvious what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you, How do I print out the SQL query?

Comment: Add `echo $sql` to your code, copy the output, and add it to the OP.  I'll bet you will see something obvious.

Comment: Do you really want to insert new rows or rather set the size for a specific existing row? For the latter, take a look at @G_hi3 's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use an `UPDATE` statement, like:
`UPDATE myTable SET nameColumn = 'Forrest Gump' WHERE idColumn = 15;`

You can set multiple columns with one statement and `WHERE` clause is used like in a regular `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Thank you, UPDATE was so key. I posted my result in my question.